# Keep element positioned in same location on window resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

My webpage consists of two things: An image that will resize to any window resize and then a form with 4 textboxes positioned in a specific location over top of the image.

My problem is the textboxes move way out of position on window resize. I have spent 6+ hours pulling my hair out trying everything in css and jquery, but nothing i can get to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/ndqna/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .Wrapper
    {
        position:relative;
        min-width: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        margin:auto;
    }

    .Image
    {
        max-width: 1150px;
        max-height: 1453px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .Form
    {
        position: relative;
        top:-260px;
        left: 200px;
        width: 130px;
        border: solid 1px #000;
    }
</style>
</head>
  <body>
      <div class="Wrapper">
        <div>
            <img src="image.png" class="Image" />
        </div>
        <div class="Form">
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Full Window: [image]

Resized Window: [image]

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? your markup+css doens't re-create the layout in your screenshot

Comment: Where is that black box coming from? Is it part of the image?

Comment: @Blazemonger - Yes it is the image.

Comment: Can you put the image somewhere where we can view it? imgur.com or something. If you're trying to position your form over it, but also make the image resizable, then you're always going to have a problem. It might be better to give the form a black background instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ndqna/

Comment: You may try `position: relative` for elements which are inside and try playing with margin, padding etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you should set the max dimension to the wrapper, and just make the image take up 100% width. Also you should position the form absolute in stead of relative, and position it from the bottom. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ndqna/2/

That beeing said, the effect is not yet 100% flawless. As the image scales, the position of the form will need to change. You could try to approach the position by using percentages. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ndqna/3/

```
.Form
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 15%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

As you will notice it is still not perfect. If you really want exact positioning, you will need to do some scripting to calculate the exact position. Before you start writing your jQuery code however, why don't you set the 'box' as a background for your form, and remove it from the background image of your page, by slicing up the source image? This way the positioning does not need to be pixel perfect, as the box will move along with the form...

Comment: Even though this doesnt work 100%, this is the closest to an answer. so i will mark it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because of your wrapper css. Try not using min or max in width, just use fixed width.

```
.Wrapper
    {
        position:relative;
        width: 945px;
        margin:auto;
    }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/r9wSX/)

Comment: Can you confirm by doing this the image will still increase and decrease in size with the browser resied? It still doesnt resize 100% width/height when i resize. Thanks